# How to use Redis as a cache backend for uwsgi_cache in Nginx

Tags: nginx, cache, uwsgi, redis

I'm using Nginx with HttpUwsgiModule and i want to perform caching. I know that there is a uwsgi_cache which can be used to cache pages on the local file system. But i want to use Redis to cache pages on memory.

I took a look at HttpRedis and HttpSRCacheModule but i can't figure out how to use these altogether. maybe that's just because i'm new to Nginx.

I would appreciate if anyone could give a detailed configuration example.

Comment: I strongly suggest you to give a look at: http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/CachingCookbook.html

uWSGI has more advanced logic to manage app caching (your app itself can eventually instruct it)

Comment: Thank you. But i prefer to enable caching in the Nginx level. I think this way Nginx doesn't even hit the UWSGI for cached pages and it will be faster.